# Not reading the correct property value in multi threaded program

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running into a scenario where I'm not sure why am I not reading the correct property value from a property while in multiple threads.. I have written a small console app to illustrate the situation

```
class Program
{
    private static Test MyObject;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyObject = new Test();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var obj = MyObject as Test;
            Console.WriteLine("1: " + obj.MyValue);
            Update("Thread1");
            Console.WriteLine("2: " + obj.MyValue);
        });
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var obj = MyObject as Test;
            Console.WriteLine("3: " + obj.MyValue);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Update("Thread2");
            Console.WriteLine("4: " + obj.MyValue);
        });

        void Update(string val)
        {
            lock (MyObject)
            {
                MyObject.MyValue = val;
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(400);
        Console.WriteLine("5: " + MyObject.MyValue);
    }
}

class Test
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Running the above line I'm getting this output

```
1:
2: Thread1
3:
4: Thread2
5: Thread2
```

My expectation is "3:" should always say "3: Thread1" because same object was updated earlier. But this is not the case and I'm not sure what am I missing here... Can someone shed some light on this please?

Just a small note... if you run the code and get different order, please re-run it... I'm only interested in order like above.

Comment: Why do you think 3 should say "Thread1"? It's effectively running at the same time as your first thread, and you have no mutual exclusion on the reading of MyValue.

Comment: Can you be more specefic please... What do you mean by "mutual exclusion"

Comment: What is the reason for instantiating new `obj` instances that refer to `MyObject`?

Comment: @RufusL: the code doesn't instantiate new instances. It just copies the object reference into the `obj` local variable. I agree it's a little odd, but it should have no effect on the program operation.

Comment: @PeterDuniho True, I guess I meant "creating new references to the same instance". I also dont' see how that would have an effect on the program, which is why I was wondering what the purpose was.

Comment: @RufusL: I wonder that too. :) I mean, not only is the new variable being introduced when in fact it doesn't need to be, but there's also the extra `as Test` that is completely superfluous (after all the `MyObject` field already has the type `Test` as declared).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Your `Update()` method synchronizes *writes* to the `MyValue` property, but does nothing about *reads*. So, the runtime is free to use a cached value for the object. It's unlikely this has anything to do with your observed output, since in practice you're not likely to see this, especially on x86 hardware. But…
2. More importantly, all that your code demonstrates is that the order of *output* can be misleading. The `Console` class has synchronization to ensure coherent output from multiple threads, but there's nothing in the code that ensures that if lines of output are written in a specific order, that the code leading up to those lines of output (such as reading the `MyValue` property) occurred in the same order that those lines of output are displayed.

In other words, just because the *console* displayed the `"2:"` line before the `"3:"` line, that doesn't actually mean that the call to `Update("Thread1")` occurred before the call to `Console.WriteLine("3: " + obj.MyValue);`

You would need to protect the individual operations with a `lock` statement as well, if you wanted to ensure the lines of output matched the order of execution of statements in the program.

To be more specific, consider the following possible order of execution for your code:

```
thread 1                                      thread 2
--------                                      --------
                                              "value" parameter <= "3: " + obj.MyValue
Console.WriteLine("1: " + obj.MyValue);
Update("Thread1");
Console.WriteLine("2: " + obj.MyValue);
                                              Console.WriteLine(value);
```

I.e. it's perfectly legal for the second thread to compute the parameter passed to `Console.WriteLine()` before the first thread gets around to even starting its logic. But then the first thread can also preempt the second thread before the second thread has a chance to actually *call* the `Console.WriteLine()` method.

If that happens, then you see the expected order of output from thread 1, but the output from thread 2 writes an apparently-stale version of the `MyValue` property, because it was retrieved before thread 1 got to run any of its logic.

To address that *specific* scenario, you could use `lock` for the `WriteLine()` calls. E.g.:

```
lock (MyObject) Console.WriteLine("1: " + obj.MyValue);
```

Note that you'd need to put that on *every* call to `Console.WriteLine()`. That would ensure that whatever value is written to the console is the most up-to-date value for the property at the time the call was made.

Comment: Can you show code sample of how would you write the code given your points please?